# Order without new query in flexigrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

I have a problem with flexigrid. When the page loads first, it runs a query.
Then, when I **(1)change the sort order**, or **(2)go to the next page**, it runs a new query(with different parameters), which is slow.

I'd like to make it faster. I know that, when we load the page, the result of the query goes into a php array.
Is it possible to keep this array(maybe put it in a json array), and when we want to do **(1)** or **(2)**, we just have to modify this array, and refresh the grid? How can I implement this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load first time data in a json object using an ajax request then in success callback function of this request load data to flexigrid using this json object. But the first ajax request will need `all the data from database` (db request). So all your user, even then need just first ten rows, will download from your server all the data each time they go to your flexigrid web page, which is not a good way to go. But its depends if you have 20 rows in your data table or let's say 100000...